# ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all() while simulation observations

Tags: python

I want to simulate some observations from a uniform distribution and a 2 dimensional normal distribution and calculate the mean, but I get the error
`ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()`
in line 5, but when I change `A != None` to `A.any() == True` I get `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'any'` how can I fix this?

```
import numpy as np
import random

def getmean(A):
    if A != None:
        return np.sum(A)/len(A)
    else:
        return 0


for n in [1, 50, 1000]:
    unifs = []
    normals = []

    # uniform
    for i in range(n):
        unifs.append(random.random())

    # normal
    for i in range(n):
        normals.append(np.array([np.random.normal(0, 1),
                                 np.random.normal(0, 1)]))
    normals = np.array(normals)

    print("n:", n, "normal mean:", getmean(unifs))
    print("n:", n, "unif mean:", getmean(normals))
```

Comment: Did you mean to write `if A is not None:`? But you are never calling your function with a value of `None`, so why compare with `None`? Perhaps what you really want here is `if len(A) > 0:`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand why you use `if A != None:` comparison or why you need `any()` for the purpose you said in your question but you just need to check if A has any member or not and for this purpose, you can use any of the following methods instead:

```py
...
    if A:
...
```

or

```py
...
    if len(A):
...
```

or

```py
...
    if len(A) != 0:
...
```

But anyway, I explain `any()` function here for you.

`list` or other data structure in python doesn't have `.any()` method themselves. There is a function called `any()` and you can use for all iterable objects in python like `list`, `tuple` etc. and you can use it in this way:

```py
sample_list = [0, 1, 2]
print(any(sample_list))
# prints: True

sample_list2 = [] # or [0, 0, 0]
print(any(sample_list2))
# prints: False
```